# How do I store user given data in registry keys at install time from NSIS installer?

Tags: installation, registry, nsis, registrykey

I have program which has some values which vary from computer to computer but are only set once at the initialization of the program. (i.e. a machine id value). The program is installed a NSIS compiled installer.

Currently the values are set on first run time of the program application, however I wanted to tidy this up and set it in the installer instead.

Is it possible to ask the user to enter the values into the installer and then safe these to register keys to be read from the application? What would be the best way to implement this?

(The nsis source forge seems to be down unfortunately)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build dialogs using [nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html). If SourceForge is down, have a look at the your local documentation `%PROGRAMFILES%\NSIS\Docs` and the examples `%PROGRAMFILES%\NSIS\Examples`.

For registry operations, take a look at [ReadRegStr](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/ReadRegStr.md)/[WriteRegStr](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/WriteRegStr.md) or [ReadRegDWORD](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/ReadRegDWORD.md)/[WriteRegDWORD](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/ReadRegDWORD.md) for a start.